# Class 'MongoId' not found (Zend Framework with MongoDB Doctrine)

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, zend-framework2, php-mongodb

Im' currently trying to integrate MongoDB with Doctrine in ZendFramework. I did a lot of tutorial (on StackOverflow or anywhere else) but nothing is really working.

I followed step by step a tutorial: http://www.bigwisu.com/2012/10/03/zend-framework-2-doctrine-odm and I got an error that I don't understand.

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoId' not found in /home/prooxi/www/zframework/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Types/IdType.php on line 38
```

The IdType.php is source code for the mongoDB, so the error must be somewhere else.
Here is the files I have. (Admin is the name of the module)

config/application.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
               'Application',
               'DoctrineModule',
               'DoctrineMongoODMModule',
               'Udmin',
               'Listing',
               'Admin',
    ),

    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),

        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),

    ),

);
```

config/autoload/module.doctrine-mongo-odm.local.php

```
<?php
return array(
         'doctrine' => array(

                 'connection' => array(
                               'odm_default' => array(
                                          'server'           => 'MYDBADRESS',
                                          'port'             => '27017',
                                          /* 'connectionString' => null, */
                                          /* 'user'             => null, */
                                          /* 'password'         => null, */
                                          'dbname'           => 'px_boutique_test27',
                                          'options'          => array()
                                          ),
                               ),

                 'configuration' => array(
                              'odm_default' => array(
                                         'metadata_cache'     => 'array',
                                         'driver'             => 'odm_default',
                                         'generate_proxies'   => true,
                                         'proxy_dir'          => 'data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Proxy',
                                         /* 'proxy_dir'          => __DIR__ . '/module/Admin/src/Admin/Model/Proxy',  */
                                         /* 'proxy_dir'          => __DIR__ . '/module/Udmin/src/Udmin/Model/Proxy', */
                                         'proxy_namespace'    => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Proxy',
                                         /* 'proxy_namespace'    => 'Udmin\Model\Proxy', */
                                         'generate_hydrators' => true,
                                         'hydrator_dir'       => 'data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Hydrator',
                                         /* 'hydrator_dir'       => __DIR__ . '/module/Udmin/src/Udmin/Model/Hydrator', */
                                         'hydrator_namespace' => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Hydrator',
                                         /* 'hydrator_namespace' => 'Udmin\Model\Hydrator', */
                                         'default_db'         => 'test27',
                                         'filters'            => array(),  // array('filterName' => 'BSON\Filter\Class'),
                                         /* 'logger'             => null // 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Logging\DebugStack' */
                                         )
                              ),

                 'driver' => array(
                           'odm_default' => array(
                                      'drivers' => array(
                                                 'Admin\Document' => 'aplikasi'
                                                 )
                                      ),
                           'aplikasi' => array(
                                       'class' => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                                       'cache' => 'array',
                                       'paths' => array(
                                            'module/Admin/src/Admin/Document'
                                            )
                                       )
                           ),
                 'documentmanager' => array(
                                'odm_default' => array(
                                           'connection'    => 'odm_default',
                                           'configuration' => 'odm_default',
                                           'eventmanager' => 'odm_default'
                                           )
                                ),
                 'eventmanager' => array(
                             'odm_default' => array(
                                        'subscribers' => array()
                                        )
                             ),              

                 ),
         );
```

Module/Admin/Src/Admin/Controller/AdminController.php

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Mongo;
use Zend\Session\SaveHandler\MongoDB;
use Zend\Session\SaveHandler\MongoDBOptions;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;
use Admin\Document\Boutique;

 class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
 {
     public function indexAction()
     {
       $dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');
       $b = new Boutique();

       /* $dm->getRepository('Admin\Document\Boutique')->findAll(); */
       $dm->find('Admin\Document\Boutique', '52e6c677362dca7fcd40ab09');
     }
}
```

Module/Admin/config/module.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
         'controllers' => array(
                    'invokables' => array(
                              'Admin\Controller\Admin' => 'Admin\Controller\AdminController',
                              ),
                    ),

         'router' => array(
                   'routes' => array(
                         'admin' => array(
                                  'type'    => 'segment',
                                  'options' => array(
                                             'route'    => '/admin[/][:action][/:id]',
                                             'constraints' => array(
                                                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                                        ),
                                             'defaults' => array(
                                                     'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Admin',
                                                     'action'     => 'index',
                                                     ),
                                             ),
                                  ),
                         ),
                   ),

         'view_manager' => array(
                     'template_path_stack' => array(
                                    'admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
                                    ),
                     ),

         );
```

The purpose of the module is to connect to an existing MongoDB databate and just make a list of all the document in it.

Thank you !

Gilles

Comment: Have you made sure that the Mongo driver for PHP has been installed?

Comment: Yap, the mongo driver is installed !

Comment: Have you either namespaced the class using a `use` statement or prefixed the class with a backslash; I.E `new \MongoId($id)`?

Comment: There is already "namespace Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Types" in IDType.php. Do I still need to write a "use" ?
And is the error really in IdType ? Because it's a source code, it should work (there is no error like this on the internet). It would be weird.

Comment: You would need to use \MongoId to access it from that file.

Comment: It's already done. In the source code, the error line is on "$value = new \MongoId($value);"

Comment: I'm sorry @PhillipWhelan, it's seems you were right the first time. The MongoDB Driver is installed on my server and there is "extention=mongo.so" in the php.ini file, but when I phpinfo(), no Mongo driver appears. This certainly is the error.

Comment: Hopefully you solved it.

Comment: I didn't really solved it, but I will search. If I don't find, I will certainly close this question and start another one.
thanks @PhillipWhelan !

Comment: thanks @AlexP, you solved my problem :p

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the newer mongodb extension rather than mongo extension for PHP you will need to use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID as detailed on the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) page