# Class 'MongoId' not found in Laradock application

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, laravel-5, laradock

Using Laradock (basically a set og Docker images for Laravel development), I keep getting `Class 'MongoId' not found` FatalThrowableError errors when calling `new \MongoId( $id )` in PHP.

This post [Class 'MongoId' not found (Zend Framework with MongoDB Doctrine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953352/class-mongoid-not-found-zend-framework-with-mongodb-doctrine) suggests that the reason for given error is that the PHP Mongo extension isn't enabled.

However, if I look at the `phpinfo()` output, I can see mongodb section. Doesn't that mean it's enabled?

What else could possibly cause this error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume that you are using php 7 version.

In php 7 version a new [MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) extension is used.

So instead of legacy [MongoId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) you should use [MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php)